# Failed to connect to sqlite engine driver from Liquibase

Tags: sqlite, database-migration, liquibase, sqlitejdbc

I downloaded/installed liquibase-1.9.3 and sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar into ubuntu 11.*. and put sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar in liquibase-1.9.3 /lib. and I  run:

```
java -jar liquibase-1.9.3.jar --driver=org.sqlite.JDBC --changeLogFile=assets_db.xml --url=sqlite.db update
```

and got result:
Migration Failed: Cannot find database driver: org.sqlite.JDBC

I guess there is a default java version from ubuntu:

```
java -version
```

java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.2) (6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

I saw somebody posted a similar question:
[Liquibase and SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460433/liquibase-and-sqlite)

but there is no correct answer for that. Should I have to install ant to make it working.
Please help, I almost spent whole day to find a working solution.

Thanks  a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I found out that the below works:

java -jar liquibase-1.9.3.jar --driver=org.sqlite.JDBC --classpath=lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar --changeLogFile=core.xml --url=jdbc:sqlite:sqlite.db  update

Migration successful

I added classpath for the driver jar file.